# Specific Object Type can't be typed as Record?

Tags: typescript

I want to define an interface for a general Table Row, basically it's any object, limited to attribute values as primitive types.

But when I try to assign an object of specific type to row it fails. Why? And how to make it work? I want to enforce that rows could be only objects with primitive attribute values.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUEMCMBsFNQCcD2B3AUPAHgBxUgC6iECeuiASuqALyiXwDGBAJgDwDOhSAlgHYBzADShufIaAA+ofgFcAttHhJpoOf1bwAZgPisAfBgwhQAVU4qMAwiu2QmiCytABvWZAXwAXGJ4DBUABfDBZ+blAAK14FX2dVend+Tx9QAHIAKRi04NCUcOJUNF9qNDoomKA)

```
// Table row
export type Row = Record<string, string | number | undefined>

// User
interface User { name: string }
const jim: User = { name: 'Jim' }
const row: Row = jim // <== Error
```

Error

```
Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'Row'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'User'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces can be extended. Without an index type restricting it, an object that *extends* User that can be stored in a User-typed variable could have other properties.

```
// User
interface User { name: string }
interface FooUser extends User { foo(): void; }
const jim: FooUser = { name: 'Jim', foo() {} }
const jimAsUser: User = jim;
const row: Row = jim;  // fails as it should:
                       // foo is not a string, number, or undefined!
```

Note that if you use `type` rather than `interface`, it is *safer*: Extra properties in subinterfaces are not expected. That said, Typescript does allow this, even though it shouldn't. `type` and `interface` have some subtle details, which [the TypeScript handbook alludes to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#interfaces-vs-intersections) (though without getting into this particular case).

```
// UserAsType
type UserAsType = { name: string };
const jimAsType: UserAsType = { name: 'Jim' }
const jimAsTypeFromFooUser: UserAsType = jim;  // this *should* fail
const row2: Row = jimAsType
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUEMCMBsFNQCcD2B3AUPAHgBxUgC6iECeuiASuqALyiXwDGBAJgDwDOhSAlgHYBzADShufIaAA+ofgFcAttHhJpoOf1bwAZgPisAfBgwhQAVU4qMAwiu2QmiCytABvWZAXwAXGJ4DBUABfa35bJHtHUAAxFBRnVRxbTU5zS1V3bTiACgBKXwA3FF5WAG5gjBZ+blAAK14FX1j49Lo3Dy9fAHIAKQau0SyUPLcgiqqa+oUAQU4E3wS2qdLKlGriVDRfajQlhvLQU3teWFTIVJwKJltWbwxQB8en55eHo7jQXlT+FGJIPwkIlkimUSFEBHUmh0elYAEJjKYErNwOR4BgyBQ0ipkai2u5+J4fACAsEVhNiFMcRQFukqYh6PjCd0+gouuM1pMGnToqgFM15likHS9goDqZCAALL6gABUnAlKDksFYMtAx1gq3WyHQACZtjR6JTOCiKBggA)